# Count the number of unique values in a cell range that are constrained to the values matching a countif of a different cell range

Tags: excel-formula, countif, sumifs

Logically this is what I need to accomplish but I am not sure how to do so or what combination of formulas to use:
SUM or COUNTIF [ ($E$2:$E$1240 contains ("*"&H3&"*")) AND (the value in $F$2:$F$ is unique[need duplicates counted only once)]

For each E cell that contains the text from H3 ("*"&H3&"*"), there will be a certain number of values in the corresponding column F of that same row that I need to count. These can be a combination of values that appear once or more than one - and for the duplicates I only want to count them once. TIA.

E.g.,
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vATzp.png)

I've tried various combinations of the COUNTIF function but can't figure out the proper input combinations.

This one definitely not right but was trying a bunch:
=SUM(COUNTIF($E$2:$E$1240,"*"&H15&"*")-(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$1240,"????*")))